# What is this spider hunting in the tree in the night?

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

I took the following picture of this spider in northern Switzerland (alt: ~700m) with macro flash/lense.

[image: spider in thuja]

The picture was taken during the night in a cedar tree (Thuja occidentalis).

Comment: Nice picture :)

Comment: That is a really well taken picture.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, it was taken without tripod, then I was a bit lucky to got it in the focus range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's look like Sac Spider (*Clubiona lutescens*) to me.

[image]

Source: http://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/Clubionidae/Clubionidae.htm

Comment: Nice catch, I am wondering how you could find this. I tried to browse many spider database but did'nt find anything.